# How can the Cisco Packet Tracer show the port's name?

Tags: cisco, router

How can the Cisco Packet Tracer show the port's name?

<kbd>[image]</kbd>

the GNS3 can show its interface name.

<kbd>[image]</kbd>

Comment: Did the answer help you? If so you should accept the answer so that it does not keep popping up. Alternatively you can add your own answer and accept that.

Answer (score 6):

You can set the Interface in Cisco Packet Tracer menu `Options` -> `Preferences` -> `Interface`,
then check the `Always Show Port Labels in Logical Workspace`.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Go to "Options" --> "Preferences" --> "Interfaces" Then Check "Always Shows Ports and Labels"